# bash shell commands for dna sequence

Tags: text-processing, command-line

I have file with DNA sequence as in example below. How can i find count of A,T,G,C in each **column** (yes, not row, but column) using bash shell commands.

The file has 846975 rows like this:

```
AAGAAAGAAGAGGAACTTCTCTCCATCCAGCCTCATTCCACTGCACCAACTCTTCTGTGT
CGGGTTGTGCAGGAGAGAAAGGGAGCTTGGCAACTCTTTGCTGTGCTGAGTTGTGGTAGC
CCATCACTGGGTTGTAAAGTGCCTTGCCTCCTTTCCTCCCCTCCTTTTTTTTTGAGACAG
AGTCTCACTCTGTCGTCCAGGCTGAGGTGCAGTGGTGCGATCTCTGCTCACTGCAACCTC
AGCCTCCTGGGTTCAAGTGATTCTCCTGCCTCAGCCTCCCAGGAAGCTGGGACTACAGGC
ACATGCCACCACACCTGGCTAACTTTTTTTTATTTTTAGTAGAGAAAGGGTATCACCATG
TTGGCCAGGCTGGTCTTGAACTCCTGACTTCAGGTGATCCACCCACCTTGGCCCCCCAAA
GTGCTGGGGTTAAAGGCATGAGACACTGCGCCCGTCCACCTCCTCTTTTACTTGGGAGAA
ATGCACAGATTCTGGGTGCCATGTGCATTTGTTTTGGGAGTGATAATTGATCTAACTTAT
GGAAATAATACTAGATAGTTAGCGGATGGATTCTGTATCTGATGAGAGTTTTGGGCAAAA
CGAATTCCTAGTTTCTGAGTCTTATTTTTCCCCTGATTCAAGAAAACTGTGAATTATCCA
GCCAGTAAAAAACTCTCACAGCTCTGGATGTGAGTTTAGGACACTGGATTTCTACCACTC
ATTTTCTTACTACTTTTCCTGTGCAAGGATCATGGCACAAGTTGCAGTTTCCACCCTGCC
CATTGAAGATGAGGAGTCTGTTGAAGATGAGGAGTCCTTGGAGAGCAGGATGGTGGTGAC
ATTCCTGTCAGCTCTCGCCTCCATGGTCAGACCTTCTGTTCTCACATTCTGTAGTTCGGT
AGGACTGGGCGGTAGATAAGGTTGATTTGTTTTCGTAGAACTTACAATTTTGTGATTTTT
AGTTCTAATGAGTAGACCTTTTTCGTGAATAGTAGTTACGATCAAACACCTCTGACCAAA
```

For this example, the output for the first column is supposed to be `A=9,T=1,G=3,C=4`.

Comment: *in each column* - you mean in each **row**?

Comment: i have large sequence with 846975 rows ...it would be better if u suggest me column wise A,T,G,C count....

Comment: *column wise A,T,G,C count* - post how should look the expected result (at least few lines)

Comment: for the above sequence i have submitted...the asuumed output should be like     A=9 ,T=1,G=3,C=4

Comment: so [my answer in second section columnwise](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/397177/72456) answering your  question while other answers are per row, please [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/397167/edit)  your post with [the comment as you clarified](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/397167/bash-shell-commands-for-dna-sequence#comment708915_397167)

Comment: i didn't get result for the program which was in the second section.for example output should be like this                   A         T         G         C
 Base 0 =>      2182    2242    2739    2670
 Base 1 =>      2248    2287    2693    2605
 Base 2 =>      2224    2272    2718    2619
 Base 3 =>      2205    2304    2694    2630
 Base 4 =>      2142    2350    2690    2651
 Base 5 =>      2173    2337    2644    2679
 Base 6 =>      2188    2263    2723    2659

Answer (score 1):

In general case where your `awk` does support null/empty field separator (this is `gawk` specific), you can do with something like below (when you want counts per line).

```bsh
gawk -F '' '{for (x=1;x<=NF;x++) arr[NR$x]++;
    for (i in arr) printf("%s:%d\t", i, arr[i]);delete arr;print ""}' infile
```

---

**NO, if you need really counts per each column (assuming empty filed separator)**, first you need to transform the input data from column into rows, then do the same as above.

```bsh
gawk -F '' '{for (x=1;x<=NF;x++) arr[NR$x]++;
    for (i in arr) printf("%s:%d\t", i, arr[i]);delete arr;print ""}' \
<(gawk -F '' '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) ctr[i]=ctr[i]$i} 
    END{for (i in ctr) print ctr[i]}' infile)
```

With below `awk` script we are transposing the columns into rows.

```bsh
gawk -F '' '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) ctr[i]=ctr[i]$i} 
    END{for (i in ctr) print ctr[i]}' infile
```

You can use below command instead of above one for transposing.

```
sed 's/./& /g' in|datamash -t ' ' transpose |sed 's/ //g'
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you meant *to find count of A,T,G,C in each **row***.

GNU **awk** solution:

```
awk -v FPAT="[A-Z]" '{ 
           printf "A: %s, T: %s, G: %s, C: %s\n",
           gsub("A",""),gsub("T",""),gsub("G",""),gsub("C","") 
       }' file
```

The output:

```
A: 17, T: 15, G: 9, C: 19
A: 11, T: 16, G: 24, C: 9
A: 8, T: 23, G: 10, C: 19
A: 9, T: 16, G: 16, C: 19
A: 11, T: 13, G: 16, C: 20
A: 17, T: 20, G: 10, C: 13
A: 11, T: 14, G: 13, C: 22
A: 12, T: 15, G: 17, C: 16
A: 14, T: 23, G: 15, C: 8
A: 20, T: 18, G: 17, C: 5
A: 16, T: 23, G: 8, C: 13
A: 17, T: 16, G: 12, C: 15
A: 12, T: 21, G: 10, C: 17
A: 16, T: 14, G: 24, C: 6
A: 8, T: 22, G: 11, C: 19
A: 14, T: 25, G: 16, C: 5
A: 20, T: 18, G: 10, C: 12
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm assuming that the user want's to count the bases in each row.

Using Perl:

```
$ perl -ne 'chomp; printf("%s\t%2d %2d %2d %2d\n", $_, tr/A/A/, tr/C/C/, tr/G/G/, tr/T/T/)' file
AAGAAAGAAGAGGAACTTCTCTCCATCCAGCCTCATTCCACTGCACCAACTCTTCTGTGT    17 19  9 15
CGGGTTGTGCAGGAGAGAAAGGGAGCTTGGCAACTCTTTGCTGTGCTGAGTTGTGGTAGC    11  9 24 16
CCATCACTGGGTTGTAAAGTGCCTTGCCTCCTTTCCTCCCCTCCTTTTTTTTTGAGACAG     8 19 10 23
AGTCTCACTCTGTCGTCCAGGCTGAGGTGCAGTGGTGCGATCTCTGCTCACTGCAACCTC     9 19 16 16
AGCCTCCTGGGTTCAAGTGATTCTCCTGCCTCAGCCTCCCAGGAAGCTGGGACTACAGGC    11 20 16 13
ACATGCCACCACACCTGGCTAACTTTTTTTTATTTTTAGTAGAGAAAGGGTATCACCATG    17 13 10 20
TTGGCCAGGCTGGTCTTGAACTCCTGACTTCAGGTGATCCACCCACCTTGGCCCCCCAAA    11 22 13 14
GTGCTGGGGTTAAAGGCATGAGACACTGCGCCCGTCCACCTCCTCTTTTACTTGGGAGAA    12 16 17 15
ATGCACAGATTCTGGGTGCCATGTGCATTTGTTTTGGGAGTGATAATTGATCTAACTTAT    14  8 15 23
GGAAATAATACTAGATAGTTAGCGGATGGATTCTGTATCTGATGAGAGTTTTGGGCAAAA    20  5 17 18
CGAATTCCTAGTTTCTGAGTCTTATTTTTCCCCTGATTCAAGAAAACTGTGAATTATCCA    16 13  8 23
GCCAGTAAAAAACTCTCACAGCTCTGGATGTGAGTTTAGGACACTGGATTTCTACCACTC    17 15 12 16
ATTTTCTTACTACTTTTCCTGTGCAAGGATCATGGCACAAGTTGCAGTTTCCACCCTGCC    12 17 10 21
CATTGAAGATGAGGAGTCTGTTGAAGATGAGGAGTCCTTGGAGAGCAGGATGGTGGTGAC    16  6 24 14
ATTCCTGTCAGCTCTCGCCTCCATGGTCAGACCTTCTGTTCTCACATTCTGTAGTTCGGT     8 19 11 22
AGGACTGGGCGGTAGATAAGGTTGATTTGTTTTCGTAGAACTTACAATTTTGTGATTTTT    14  5 16 25
AGTTCTAATGAGTAGACCTTTTTCGTGAATAGTAGTTACGATCAAACACCTCTGACCAAA    20 12 10 18
```

Or

```
$ perl -ne 'BEGIN { print(" A  C  G  T\n") } printf("%2d %2d %2d %2d\n", tr/A/A/, tr/C/C/, tr/G/G/, tr/T/T/)' file
 A  C  G  T
17 19  9 15
11  9 24 16
 8 19 10 23
 9 19 16 16
11 20 16 13
17 13 10 20
11 22 13 14
12 16 17 15
14  8 15 23
20  5 17 18
16 13  8 23
17 15 12 16
12 17 10 21
16  6 24 14
 8 19 11 22
14  5 16 25
20 12 10 18
```

The `tr` operator in Perl does transliteration, pretty much like the `tr` utility in the shell.  It returns the number of characters transliterated.